# Unity Mesh Deformation with Collisions

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, collision-detection, mesh

How to access the 2D mesh of a sprite by code then change the shape of the sprite?

I want to make a game similar to [Agario](http://www.agar.io)

I just was wondering how to achieve this jelly form when touching objects either by collisions or triggers ?

> I would like to see more answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scaling won't get you the kind of deformations you want. Coding deformations the way agar.io does it from scratch is quite difficult. I can see multiple ways of doing this, so I'm going to list them from most recommended to least recommended:

1. Start with a flat 3D mesh and render your sprite on it as a texture so you basically get a billboard. Then use collision events to get the [contact points](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-contacts.html) and use math to figure out how to move the [mesh's vertices](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-vertices.html) in response to the contact. You can see someone achieving that effect [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rw6wNRdmBpU) and **you can see a full blown tutorial for a sphere [here](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/mesh-deformation/), a highly recommended read**. Your idea with getting the line from the center of the circle via the contact position and decreasing its length is sound, though the implementation is a bit more complex than that if you want it to behave like agar.io.
2. Get [Anima2D](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/unity-anima2d-79840), a free asset that can among other things convert sprites to meshes. Then again use collision events to get the contact points and distort the mesh.
3. Use Anima2D or a different asset with equivalent capabilities and figure out how to use 2D bones in order to get something like agar.io's effect. You could also try 3D bones on a plane/billboard mesh.
4. Send the collision data to a vertex shader that is programmed to deform the thing it's rendering.

Comment: Thanks So much for you answer I appreciate that hard work. I found this URL [https://answers.unity.com/questions/847784/mesh-deformation-with-collisions.html] I think it is close to what I need maybee. Isn't it?

Comment: I think I will try to be far from taking the shader choice cause it is a whole new concept language to learn? I will try the other choices. By the way youtube Link you shared Is what I sawed before posting this question cause it is what I need I think so.

Comment: Yes, I also suggest against the shader solution. It would require a solid grasp of hlsl / ShaderLab. It's good to focus on learning only a few things at a time. That URL is on the right track, but I think you should follow the tutorial I linked. After following it from start to finish, you won't have any problem implementing something similar in 2D and tweaking it to behave the way you want (It will technically still be 3D but just with one dimension being flat).

Comment: OK So that documentation you shared is about 3D sphere Do I have to change the `Vector3` to `Vector2` or just keep them as is?Do I have to convert any code back to 2D?

Comment: afaik, Unity3D does not have the concept of a 2D mesh. All meshes are 3D but they can be treated as 2D if you leave one of the three components of the Vector3 struct as zero and orient the mesh so it's facing the camera. So I would continue using Vector3 and just leave y as zero for example, if you want the camera to look at the mesh from above. I would also suggest going through the whole tutorial with no modification and making a sphere, then doing it again for a circle. If you try to do the tutorial and re-adapt it for a circle as you go, it will be harder to understand and follow.

Answer (score 1):

you can contact gameobjects with Trigger function. That function is working automatically with GameObject's tag names. Here is how you can get [Triger function](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html)

And also you can change size of GameObjects when they touch each other
[More info about scaling](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localScale.html)

you can code almost anything you want and here is about [Mesh of sprite](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html)

Comment: Thanks For the answer. So I can use the trigger function to get the contact points then make them collapse partially to the center of the circle This might be simple But Am I talking right?

Comment: Can I do this by getting the contact point then get the line from the center of the circle to the position of the contact point then decrease its length Thanks In Advance?

Comment: there is have function to find where  GameObjects are contacting. Here is about  [ContactPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContactPoint-point.html)